# Android/Firebase: Why does onDataChange() returns null values?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My application allows a user to add details about a place when a marker is added on the Google map. These details are stored within Firebase with all details which are NOT null.

Here is the UPDATED tree:

```
{
  "Algiers" : {
    "Description" : "Capital of Algeria",
    "Latitude" : 36.77202162442747,
    "Longitude" : 3.0560945346951485,
    "Rating" : "9",
    "Type" : "Town"
  },
  "Brussels" : {
    "Description" : "Capital of Belgium",
    "Latitude" : 50.850103621427685,
    "Longitude" : 4.3520765751600266,
    "Rating" : "8",
    "Type" : "Town"
  },
  "Burger King" : {
    "Description" : "Fast but not healthy food",
    "Latitude" : 51.236331,
    "Longitude" : -0.575385,
    "Rating" : 5.29,
    "Type" : "Restaurant"
  },
  "Chippy Pizza" : {
    "Description" : "Best American pizza ever",
    "Latitude" : 36.72722332469427,
    "Longitude" : 3.0647138133645058,
    "Rating" : "10",
    "Type" : "Restaurant"
  },
  "European Parliament" : {
    "Description" : "Some decisions about Europe are done there",
    "Latitude" : 50.83868986886192,
    "Longitude" : 4.375510700047016,
    "Rating" : "8",
    "Type" : "Museum"
  },
  "Friary Center McDonalds" : {
    "Description" : "Good food",
    "Latitude" : 51.23544690507358,
    "Longitude" : -0.5764660611748695,
    "Rating" : "7.4",
    "Type" : "Restaurant"
  },
  "Guildford Town Center" : {
    "Description" : "Town center of Guildford",
    "Latitude" : 51.23622,
    "Longitude" : -0.570409,
    "Rating" : 8.74,
    "Type" : "Town"
  },
  "Guildfords Castle" : {
    "Description" : "Very old castle",
    "Latitude" : 51.23428622281793,
    "Longitude" : -0.5723629519343376,
    "Rating" : "8",
    "Type" : "Museum"
  },
  "Guildfords Hospital" : {
    "Description" : "Treats all types of pathologies",
    "Latitude" : 51.240506,
    "Longitude" : -0.60838,
    "Rating" : "9",
    "Type" : "Hospital"
  },
  "Guildfords Museum" : {
    "Description" : "Museum with several exhibitions",
    "Latitude" : 51.233797,
    "Longitude" : -0.573549,
    "Rating" : "7.84",
    "Type" : "Museum"
  },
  "Martyrs Monument" : {
    "Description" : "Describes the History of Algeria",
    "Latitude" : 36.745560268045196,
    "Longitude" : 3.0698012933135033,
    "Rating" : "10",
    "Type" : "Museum"
  },
  "Military Hospital" : {
    "Description" : "Excellent Hospital",
    "Latitude" : 36.71973881144668,
    "Longitude" : 3.063882999122143,
    "Rating" : "10",
    "Type" : "Hospital"
  },
  "Mount Alvernia Hospital" : {
    "Description" : "Small and correct hospital",
    "Latitude" : 51.23583085374619,
    "Longitude" : -0.5647089332342148,
    "Rating" : "7",
    "Type" : "Hospital"
  },
  "Mustapha Bacha Hospital" : {
    "Description" : "Complete Hospital",
    "Latitude" : 36.76243892522928,
    "Longitude" : 3.053263798356056,
    "Rating" : "7",
    "Type" : "Hospital"
  },
  "Nandos Guildford" : {
    "Description" : "Tasty but expensive chicken",
    "Latitude" : 51.236343270137674,
    "Longitude" : -0.5743494629859924,
    "Rating" : "9",
    "Type" : "Restaurant"
  },
  "Pachéco Hospital" : {
    "Description" : "Excellent Hospital",
    "Latitude" : 50.854205318946484,
    "Longitude" : 4.349818155169487,
    "Rating" : "10",
    "Type" : "Hospital"
  },
  "Paris" : {
    "Description" : "Capital",
    "Latitude" : "48.84191426189115",
    "Longitude" : "2.3034103587269783",
    "Rating" : "8",
    "Type" : "Town"
  },
  "Starbucks Coffee" : {
    "Description" : "All types of coffee are found there",
    "Latitude" : 51.235304,
    "Longitude" : -0.575049,
    "Rating" : 7.84,
    "Type" : "Restaurant"
  },
  "Test 2" : {
    "Description" : "Test",
    "Latitude" : "26.567103702363973",
    "Longitude" : "2.967230938374996",
    "Rating" : "8",
    "Type" : "Town"
  },
  "Test Overflow" : {
    "Description" : "Test",
    "Latitude" : "31.29925316955398",
    "Longitude" : "2.439718544483185",
    "Rating" : "10",
    "Type" : "Town"
  },
  "Test3" : {
    "Description" : "Testf",
    "Latitude" : "45.24608905762172",
    "Longitude" : "3.4947332739830017",
    "Rating" : "8",
    "Type" : "Town"
  }
}
```

I am using the Firebase docs to retrieve data from my database (using `onDataChange()`).

However, my application crashes and prints me the following error:

```
05-16 14:37:15.772 13332-13332/org.com1032.flagged_v2 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                        Process: org.com1032.flagged_v2, PID: 13332
                                                                        java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference
                                                                            at org.com1032.flagged_v2.MainActivity$6.onDataChange(MainActivity.java:877)
                                                                            at com.firebase.client.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(ValueEventRegistration.java:56)
                                                                            at com.firebase.client.core.view.DataEvent.fire(DataEvent.java:45)
                                                                            at com.firebase.client.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(EventRaiser.java:38)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5219)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

After some Logs, I realized that all values of that specific key are null.

Here is the code for retrieving the data from Firebase:

```
firebaseMarkers.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                            String descPath = dataSnapshot1.getKey() + "/Description";
                            String latPath = dataSnapshot1.getKey() + "/Latitude";
                            String lonPath = dataSnapshot1.getKey() + "/Longitude";
                            String ratePath = dataSnapshot1.getKey() + "/Rating";
                            String typePath = dataSnapshot1.getKey() + "/Type";


                            Log.v("INSERTING?", "MAYBE");
                            Log.v("the KEY", dataSnapshot1.getKey());
                            Log.v("TYPE:", dataSnapshot.child(typePath) + "");
                            Log.v("NAME:", dataSnapshot1.getKey());
                            Log.v("LATITUDE:", dataSnapshot.child(latPath).getValue().toString());
                            Log.v("LONGITUDE:", dataSnapshot.child(lonPath).getValue().toString());
                            Log.v("RATING:", dataSnapshot.child(ratePath).getValue().toString());
                            Log.v("DESCRIPTION", dataSnapshot.child(descPath).getValue().toString());

                               markersDatabase.insertData(dataSnapshot.child(typePath).getValue().toString(), dataSnapshot1.getKey(),
                                    Double.parseDouble(dataSnapshot.child(latPath).getValue().toString()), Double.parseDouble(dataSnapshot.child(lonPath).getValue().toString()),
                                    dataSnapshot.child(ratePath).getValue().toString(), dataSnapshot.child(descPath).getValue().toString());




                            Log.v("INSERTED!", "YES");

                        }
                    }


                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
                        Log.v("Firebase Error", "Wow, you're asking very deep");
                    }
                });
```

Each time I add a data, everything is stored onto a local database in the phone (all duplicates are removed after).

Here is the code for adding data into the firebase:

```
fire.child(markerName.toString()).setValue(markerName.toString());
                            fire.child(markerName.toString()).child("Description").setValue(markerDescription.toString());
                            fire.child(markerName.toString()).child("Latitude").setValue(String.valueOf(point.latitude));
                            fire.child(markerName.toString()).child("Longitude").setValue(String.valueOf(point.longitude));
                            fire.child(markerName.toString()).child("Rating").setValue(markerRating.toString());
                            fire.child(markerName.toString()).child("Type").setValue(markerType.toString());

                            MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(point.latitude, point.longitude)).title(markerName);
                            map.addMarker(marker);

                            markersDatabase.insertData(markerType, markerName, point.latitude, point.longitude, markerRating, markerDescription);
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You've included a link to a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export button in your Firebase database. Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I have updated my question.

Comment: Your error message says that you're calling `toString()` on a `null` reference at `MainActivity.java:877`. Set a breakpoint there and check what exact reference is `null`.

Comment: Basically, all children of the new added key are null: 
`05-17 11:36:21.171 19678-19678/org.com1032.flagged_v2 V/the KEY: Test Overflow
05-17 11:36:21.171 19678-19678/org.com1032.flagged_v2 V/TYPE:: DataSnapshot { key = Type, value = null } ` (This is only the type, but it applies for all children of the key)
Element and chidlren in JSON file is the same as other elements with their children.

Comment: `Log.v("TYPE:", dataSnapshot1.child("Type").getValue(String.class))`

Comment: `05-18 13:48:15.297 17756-17756/org.com1032.flagged_v2 V/TYPE:: null`
I had to accomodate your log since the path of the value was not defined. Thank you for your attention.

Comment: All I can see is that your code is not in the place in your JSON tree where you expect it to be: `the KEY: Test Overflow`. That key is not present in the JSON you've shown, so you're likely listening somewhere else in the tree.

Comment: In my second comment, I have said that the key `Test Overflow` and all its children is indeed in the JSON tree and all children values are not null. I update the tree right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically, I found the answer by myself.

The problem was in inserting data into Firebase. I was using the `setValue()` method which was not really the best way with the values I was using.

The best way is to create a new `HashMap` where you will be going to put your path and the value, as the example below:

```
Map<String, String> map2 = new HashMap<String, String>();
map2.put("Description", markerDescription);
map2.put("Latitude", String.valueOf(point.latitude));
map2.put("Longitude", String.valueOf(point.longitude));
map2.put("Rating", markerRating);
map2.put("Type", markerType);
Firebase fire = new Firebase("********").child(markerName);
fire.setValue(map2);
```

This is basically the best way to insert data (at least in my case).

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand the answer... Did you realize why Firebase started to work as expected again? In my case, I have NULL the first time, but the second time and next work without problems

Comment: I am having the same issue. I write to Firebase and it is reading null. However, I know for sure the data is not null. The problem is I write as a POJO and cannot use Maps.....

Comment: Hi @tccpg288, I found a solution: frank van puffelen recommended seeing If you are calling onDataChange method twice because the second time you could get null. Another solution could be adding a handler `new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                   /*Call your method which have the ondatachange*/
                                }
                            }, 1000);` and you could get the data if `dataSnapshot.getValue()` is null

Comment: Thanks, can you check my issue here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41310298/firebase-database-data-returning-null-when-reading?noredirect=1#comment69840848_41310298

Comment: I realized to fix the null problem, I needed to add a listener (FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener) `firebaseAuth.addAuthStateListener(authListener);` on onStart event and remove it on onStop event if listener was distinct of null `if (authListener != null) { firebaseAuth.removeAuthStateListener(authListener); }`... So, I was wrong on my last coments

Answer (score 0):

The same thing was happening to me.  The data looks identical in firebase.  While debugging I could pull the data, however during runtime it would return null.  For some reason, saving the hashmap to firebase works.

BTW if you use  you can save yourself some casting.

```
    Map<String, Object> markerMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
```