# Firebase Database Data Returning Null When Reading

Tags: java, android, firebase

I am not sure why, I have explored both `.setValue()` and `.updateChildren()` methods, but for whatever reason when I read data from firebase it is returning null. Here is how I write to Firebase:

Model Poll Class:

```
@IgnoreExtraProperties
public class Poll {

private String question;
private String image_URL;

public Poll() {
}

public Poll(String Question, String Image_URL) {
    this.question = Question;
    this.image_URL = Image_URL;
}

public String getQuestion() {
    return question;
}

public void setQuestion(String question) {
    this.question = question;
}

public String getImage_URL() {
    return image_URL;
}

public void setImage_URL(String image_URL) {
    this.image_URL = image_URL;
}

@Exclude
public Map<String, Object> toMap(){
            HashMap<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();
            result.put("question", question);
            result.put("image_URL", image_URL);
            return result;
     }

   }
```

*I am following the documentation [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1VpQ.png) with my `.toMap()` method and use of `.updateChildren()`

Here is where I create my Firebase references and write to the database:

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_create);
    mStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
    mStorageRef = mStorage.getReferenceFromUrl("gs://firebase-fan-polls.appspot.com");


    mBaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    mPollsRef = mBaseRef.child("Polls");
    mAddImageButton = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.add_image_button);
    mAddAnswersButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.add_answers_button);
    mImagePreview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.preview_image);
    mCreatePollQuestion = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.create_poll_question_editText);
    mCreatePollAnswerCounter = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.create_poll_answer_counter_TextView);
    mEditTextAnswerLayout = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.create_poll_questions_answer_layout);
    mSubmitPollCreation = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.submit_poll_FAB);
    mNumberOfPollAnswersCreatedByUser = 2;
    mAnswerChoices = new ArrayList<>();
    mCreatePollAnswerCounter.setText(String.valueOf(mNumberOfPollAnswersCreatedByUser));
    for (int i = 0; i < mNumberOfPollAnswersCreatedByUser; i++) {
        createAnswerChoice(i + 1);
    }
    mAddAnswersButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mNumberOfPollAnswersCreatedByUser++;
            if (mNumberOfPollAnswersCreatedByUser > 5) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.max_create_answers, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
            createAnswerChoice(mNumberOfPollAnswersCreatedByUser);
            mCreatePollAnswerCounter.setText(String.valueOf(mNumberOfPollAnswersCreatedByUser));
        }
    });

    mSubmitPollCreation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //TODO: Need to check if poll requirements are added, i.e. Question, Answer, ......
            //check if image has been loaded first
            if (resultImageURL == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getResources().getString(R.string.no_image_selected), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }

            Poll poll = new Poll(mCreatePollQuestion.getText().toString(), resultImageURL);
            Map <String, Object> pollMap = poll.toMap();
            String key = mBaseRef.child("Polls").push().getKey();
            Map<String, Object> childUpdates = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            childUpdates.put("/Polls/" + key, pollMap);
            mBaseRef.updateChildren(childUpdates);


            if (mNumberOfPollAnswersCreatedByUser > 5) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getResources().getText(R.string.poll_answers_greater_than_five), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                mNumberOfPollAnswersCreatedByUser = 5;
            }

            Intent toHomeActivity = new Intent(CreateActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
            toHomeActivity.putExtra("viewpager_position", 2);
            startActivity(toHomeActivity);
        }
    });
```

Everything is writing to Firebase correctly, as I can see it in the database in my console. I try and read it from this activity:
public class PollFragment extends Fragment {

```
@Bind(R.id.comment_label_counter)
TextView mCommentCounter;

@Bind(R.id.comments_label_icon)
ImageView mCommentsLabelIcon;

private DatabaseReference mBaseRef;
private DatabaseReference mPollsRef;
private DatabaseReference mSelectedPollRef;

private RadioGroup mPollQuestionRadioGroup;
private RadioGroup.LayoutParams mParams;

//static
private TextView mCommentsLabel;
private TextView mTotalVoteCounter;
private TextView mSelectedVote;
private TextView mYourVotelabel;
private ViewPager mViewPager;
private int mPagerCurrentPosition;
private static final String VOTE_COUNT_LABEL = "Vote_Count";
private static final String QUESTION_LABEL = "question";
private static final String ANSWERS_LABEL = "Answers";
private static final String POLL_LABEL = "Poll";
private static final String IMAGE_URL = "image_URL";

//all date items; dynamic
private DateFormat mDateFormat;
private Date mDate;
private String mCurrentDateString;
private TextView mPollQuestion;
private ArrayList<RadioButton> mPollAnswerArrayList;
private HorizontalBarChart mPollResults;
ArrayList<BarEntry> pollResultChartValues;
private BarDataSet data;
private ArrayList<IBarDataSet> dataSets;
private ValueEventListener valueEventListener;
private String pollID;
private int mPollIndex;
private ProgressBar mProgressBar;

private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

public PollFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

/**
 * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
 * this fragment using the provided parameters.
 *
 * @return A new instance of fragment PollFragment.
 */
// TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
// TODO: Decide where to add comments button;
public static PollFragment newInstance(String pollIndex) {
    PollFragment fragment = new PollFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("POLL_ID", pollIndex);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //TODO: check navigation to see if there are different ID's being generated from trending, following, and new fragments
    Bundle args = getArguments();
    String pollID = args.getString("POLL_ID");
    Log.v("TAG", "THE PASSED ID Is " + pollID);
    mBaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    mPollsRef = mBaseRef.child(POLL_LABEL);
    mSelectedPollRef = mPollsRef.child(pollID);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO: Add Fragment Code to check if savedInstanceState == null; add at Activity Level?


    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    final ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_poll, container, false);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, rootView);
    getActivity().setTitle(R.string.todays_polls_title);

    //Initialize Poll Results Bar Chart and set to Invisible
    mPollResults = (HorizontalBarChart) rootView.findViewById(R.id.poll_results_chart);
    mPollResults.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
    mPollResults.setNoDataTextDescription(getResources().getString(R.string.no_results_description));
    mPollResults.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    mTotalVoteCounter = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.total_vote_counter);
    mCommentCounter = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.comment_label_counter);
    mCommentCounter = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.comment_label_counter);

    mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar_white);

    mPollQuestion = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.poll_question);
    mPollQuestion.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.poll_question_text_size));
    mPollQuestionRadioGroup = (RadioGroup) rootView.findViewById(R.id.poll_question_group);



    mSelectedPollRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            Log.v("TAG", dataSnapshot.getKey());

            //add question
            String pollQuestion = (String) dataSnapshot.child(QUESTION_LABEL).getValue();
            Log.v("TAG", "THE POLL QUESTION IS " + pollQuestion);
            mPollQuestion.setText(pollQuestion);
            mPollQuestion.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);



            //add image
            String pollImageURL = (String) dataSnapshot.child(IMAGE_URL).getValue();
            Log.v("TAG", "THE POLL IMAGE URL IS" + pollImageURL);
            Picasso.with(getActivity())
                    .load(pollImageURL)
                    .fit()
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.loading_spinner_white)
                    .into((ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.poll_image));
```

Finally, here is my Firebase Database:

[image]

Comment: can you put your database structure? And also please show the initialization of `mBaseRef` and `mSelectedPollRef`, and what is the value of `QUESTION_LABEL`

Comment: Your code is confusing to me.  We can't see what poll.toMap() does, nor do we know where your database references point.  Also, why do you need two maps to write what appears to be a single poll object?  And what happens if you log the value of the dataSnapshot - do you get anything that you expect?

Comment: I apologize for not being clear in my original post, please see revised code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Careless mistake:

```
private static final String POLL_LABEL = "Poll";
```

Should be:

```
private static final String POLL_LABEL = "Polls";
```

The first choice was not the correct Firebase referencing thus causing the error.